# How to check the cpu temperatures core by core?

Tags: cpu, temperature, sensors

I have a Phenom X3-8450e which has a total of 3 cores. But when I ran "sensors" on a terminal I got this:

```
$ sensors
atk0110-acpi-0  
Adapter: ACPI interface  
Vcore Voltage:      +0.99 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)  
+3.3 Voltage:      +3.38 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)  
+5 Voltage:        +5.02 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)  
+12 Voltage:      +11.98 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)  
CPU FAN Speed:     1985 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)  
CHASSIS FAN Speed:    0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)  
POWER FAN Speed:      0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)  
CPU Temperature:    +32.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)  
MB Temperature:     +27.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

As you can see it only displays a combined `CPU Temperature:    +32.0°C`.

But how can I show the individual temperature of each core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sensors-detect` to configure the missing sensors, if they are available.

At my machine, there is a second sensor device handling the per-core sensors:

```
[...]
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 0:         +53.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 1:         +53.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 2:         +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 3:         +54.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the GUI application **[XSensors](http://freecode.com/projects/xsensors)**. It will show you multiple tabs. One of them will be **atk0110** as in the output you posted. One of the other tabs should display the core temperatures (may have the name **coretemp**).

[image]
Image from [linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com](http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/05/installng-xsensors-and-lm-sensors-on.html)

Comment: That should show the same as `sensors`, but the problem is that `coretemp` is missing there.